# How to open a new tab on button click in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a button which navigate user to another page. (It has to be button not link). I want to open the page in new tab (or even new window!). Do I have to use JavaScript? or is there any other way! I'll appreciate your help.

Cheers.

Comment: Just want to know, why do you need it to be a button and how do you navigate site using button?

Comment: Well, It's a kind of personalized button which my colleges use. The navigation is something like this:
                        <button 
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                url="<%= course_session.url %>"
                                href="#dlg_<%= course_session.id %>"
                          Button
                        </button>

Comment: By customized does it mean design/css wise? Why not apply the same style to an anchor so it would be easier to use href.

Comment: But in any case, are you open to using javascript?

Comment: Css design and also some coding stuff. depends on situation the button will change it's behaviour a little bit. I prefer not to touch it but if I have to I will.
And about JavaScript. Yeah, I not good at JavaScript but I have to start from somewhere! :)

Comment: Posted one that uses javascript. Didn't test it fully but you'll get the gist of it. :) Have a good day Venus!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To expand on the answers suggesting using `target="_blank" in Rails...

If you're using the `button_to` helper, this is automatically wrapped in a form by Rails.  It's the `form` tag that needs this attribute.  To get it, pass it as a value in the hash of html options, for example:

```
button_to t(:translated_text), foo_path(foo.id), class: 'btn btn-primary', form: {target: '_blank'}
```

the `class:` and `form:` are elements of the `html_options` hash. The `form:` option is special because it tell Rails you want to pass the HTML option to the `form` tag, instead of the `input` tag of the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather an html question. If you want to use buttons instead of links, you can provide the target attribute to the form as described here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
   window.open('pageName');
```

})

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` is what you want, but it only works on forms and links.

You can style a link to look like a button with css quite easily, which would be the cleanest way to achieve what you are after.

Unless your button is within a form, then you can just add `target="_blank"` to your form and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript, this selects all your buttons that have href attribute

```
$("button[href]").click(function() {
   window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This actually opens a new window but I think when the browser forces it to open in new tab, it will open in a new tab.

Cheers!